# CodeIgniter - MySql timestamp/datetime keep giving me zeros when inserting

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, datetime, timestamp

I am current using CodeIgniter 2.2.2 and I have the following code inside my modal:

```
$this->createDate = time();
$this->db->insert('someDB_Table', $this);
```

Where my createDate type is a timestamp (i also tried datetime). But this is giving me all zeros when inserting inside DB. Is there other way to get around this? Like such: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Comment: What's the output for `var_dump($this)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this(array input method)

```
 $my_array = array(
'database_field' => $this->input->post('input_form_field'),
'time_stamp'       => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
);
 $this->db->insert('someDB_Table', $my_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the error:

```
this->createDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Apparently Datetime/Timestamp requires a format to be recognizes in time at insertion. So here you go!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your are storing the date inside the variable "createDate" which is stored in your structure variable $this. So it is quite the same as $this['createDate'] = time();
Try to do :

```
$this = time();
$this->db->insert('someDB_Table', $this);
```

or

```
$this->createDate = time();
$this->db->insert('someDB_Table', $this->createDate);
```

I haven't tested it but both of them should work. Also check your table column name (Sometimes bugs comes from that).

Otherwise this is how I do it almost every time:

```
$date = time();
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `someDB_Table`(`createDate`) VALUES (`$date`)");
```

Good luck ;)

Comment: well my db have other fields too. so i can't really just pass my object into the entire table